# How to disable variable line height in VS 2013 with Productivity Power Tools?

Tags: visual-studio-2013

After installing VS 2013 and Productivity Power Tools I noticed that lines with only curly brackets have lower height than the normal code lines... is there a way to disable this?

Comment: Modified to mention PPT as this was the feature of PPT, not VS itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a feature that comes with the Productivity Power Tools extension. To disable it, go to Tools -> Options -> Productivity Power Tools and switch the Syntactic Line Compression feature to OFF.